# Is it allowed to take Som out of Uzbekistan?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, money, central-asia, uzbekistan

I always take some money home as a souvenir. Uzbekistan seems to have very strict laws regarding cash export. Am I allowed to take some of their local currency out of the country?

Comment: I was there last year and left with a pocket full of loose soʻm as a souvenir for my son. At the control point they examined my entry declaration and tallied up my so'm (plus $, plus £) and it tallied up less than my declaration, no problem. Cash points are rare so bring your cash, preferably $ before you arrive. £ works also but not as good as $.

Comment: Hears where? There are laws about exporting foreign currency, not local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no prohibition, according to the International Air Transport Association (IATA) Travel Centre, regarding [Uzbekistan Currency Export regulations](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/UZ-Uzbekistan-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm):

> Export allowed for non-residents:
>   - unlimited local currency (Uzbek Som-UZS);
>   - foreign currencies not exceeding amount declared upon arrival. Proof of lawful exchange into Uzbek Som is required from passengers spending more than USD 2,000.-. Passengers failing to submit this proof have to pay a fine of 30 percent of the amount imported.

Comment: I think with the current value of the Som (and their comparatively small denomination) , I can't really imagine it being practical to remove significant amounts of Som from Uzbekistan anyway.